# C# Regular Expression to break pairs of semicolon-delimited values into array

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Given the following strings

```
7;#User One
7;#User Two;#9;#User Two
7;#User Two;#9;#User Two;#123;#User Three
```

I would like to build a regular expression that "breaks" these apart so that each string returns the following matches:

```
["7;#User One"]
["7;#User Two", "9;#User Two"]
["7;#User Two", "9;#User Two", "123;#User Three"]
```

I tried a few methods but can't seem to get it to work properly.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should do the trick

```
#?([0-9]+;#[a-zA-Z\s]+)
```

Comment: The first group will contain the match you want

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
#?\d*;#User [a-zA-Z]*[|#]?
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you matches on the group UserName

```
#*(?<UserName>\d+;#[^;]+)
```

It would be simply is you prepended the string with a hash and appended a semi-colon...

Comment: Yeah, Chris's start is better. would still go for ^; instead of a-z so you can have any character in user except semi-colon.

#?(\d+;#[^;]+)